# AWS WAF create custom rules

Tags: php, joomla, aws-ec2, amazon-waf

Attackers are repeatedly using the same off-the-shelf exploit to attack my server.  It doesn't work because my server is patched and I have some server side modules to prevent the exploit.

However I am wandering how I can get the AWS WAF to block these attacks as I assume it is preferable to block these upstream so to speak.

The exploit is to a Joomla CMS.  They are attempting this exploit:

https://developer.joomla.org/security-centre/894-20230201-core-improper-access-check-in-webservice-endpoints.html